# Как при нажатии button выделить все checkbox?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Код php:

```
<body>
 <button> Delete </button>   
 <button> Select All</button> 
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last login</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
 <?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
  $query = "SELECT*FROM users WHERE id>0";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die (mysqli_error($db));
  for ( $data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row );
  $result='';
  foreach ($data as $elem) 
  {
   $result.='<tr>';
      $result.='<td><input type="checkbox"></td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['username'].'</td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['lastlogin'].'</td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['Status'].'</td>';
   $result.='</tr>';
  }
  echo $result;
 ?>
</table>
```

Сама таблица: https://ibb.co/gyzbwV
Зараннее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function selectAll(btn) {
  btn.checkValue = (btn.checkValue != "on")? "on" : "off";
  var value = btn.checkValue == "on";
  
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("table input[type='checkbox']");
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].checked = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <button> Delete </button>   
 <button onclick="selectAll(this)"> Select All</button> 
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last login</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>User1</td>
    <td>May 1, 2000</td>
    <td>Locked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>User2</td>
    <td>January 1, 2018</td>
    <td>Active</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Каким образом при повторном нажатии убрать все чекбоксы?